# Save the Swatches on a ColorDialog in a C# Windows Application

Tags: c#, winforms, color-picker

I have an application where the System.Windows.Forms.ColorDialog dialog box is used as a color picker. Is there anyway that I can either (1) save the swatches the user saves in the "Custom Colors" section of this dialog or (2) create a standard set of swatches that all users would see when they open the color picker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a UserControl that just stores the RGB values for each swatch. You could easily store Custom swatches like that, as well.

Edit: Oh, and to actually answer your question, take a look at:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/19cf2bdd-7e97-4642-8272-a125fb668179

Comment: I love SO - I've been wondering how to do this for years, but it never seemed important enough to devote any research time to.

Comment: I implemented the solution from the link Michael provided. It works quite well.